# photo upload using Robot class in java

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I use a mac machine and i am trying to automate photo upload scenario.

This is the step:
1. Click on "Add photo" element in a webpage
2. It will bring up the system dialogue box to select
3. Once I select a photo in the system dialogue box (either double click the image or single click and click on "open" button ) then
4. I will see a pop up from the web page which shows the preview of the selected photo.
5.In that Pop-up I click on the "Upload" button.

The Robot code I use selects the image from my desktop, but does't do any action after that.

Any suggestions? Or any better way to do this?

```
   public photo_upload_page clickOnAddphoto() throws Exception {

        waitAndClickElement(addPhoto);

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        File file = new File("/Users/mohand/Desktop/Defect.jpg");
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(file.getAbsolutePath());
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);

        Robot robot = new Robot();

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);

        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

        robot.delay(500);

//Open Goto window

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_G);

        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);

        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);

        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_G);

//Paste the clipboard value

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);

        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);

        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);

//Press Enter key to close the Goto window and Upload window

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

        robot.delay(500);

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        waitAndClickElement(buttonUploadPhoto);

        return new photo_upload_page();
    }


}
```

Comment: "2. It will bring up the system dialogue box to select" As you already know, the dialog belongs to OS (not to browser). That's why the dialog is unreachable for any script, otherwise it would be possible to smuggle code direct to OS.

Comment: you need to evade the dialog. If you have an input field for image location, use element.sendkeys("path to your image").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just figured it out. I just added the below code couple of times after steps 4 and it worked!

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```